# Increase the size of the fonts used By XCode 4's GUI

Tags: xcode4, font-size

How can I increase the size of XCode 4's GUI fonts (not the editor, everything else)?

On my MBP 17", it's just impossible to read that XXX for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Xcode specific, but you might try launching Xcode using the resolution independent scaling built into the OS. It's the same thing you find in the Run action of a scheme, as it scale up the entire UI for an application.

Comment: seems this is the only way. it's crazy on my 27inch iMac :S

Comment: What's the point of the beautiful and dense Apple screens if you're going to reduce its resolution?  This is NOT a solution, it's an admission that there is no solution.

Comment: @ScottBiggs: No need to become emotional. I didn't write Xcode or OS X. You casually use the word "admission" as if I'm hiding something rather than trying to help a fellow developer around a tough situation. Drink a glass of wine, have a massage, and let go of some of your anger.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi: Thank you; I appreciate your sentiment and concern.  But some people won't drink the kool-ade, no matter how many headaches and ulcers it may prevent. AND...when you get in your 40s and start to lose your ability to focus on that small font on your computer screen, you will understand how important this issue is: your job may depend on it (and no, glasses are only part of the solution).

Comment: I had three operations on my eyes by the time I was three years old. I fully understand the sight challenge. It's irrelevant to the point: you sound accusational toward those who are trying to offer work-arounds for something that's not available. **Bitch at Apple.**

Comment: You can use the command line to instruct OS X what scale factor to use when launching any given app. `defaults write com.vendor.program.blah.blah AppleDisplayScaleFactor 2.0` for 2x scaling, for example.