# How to change font size in Xcode 4 Navigator?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

In XCode3 there was a workaround with editing some library file, is there any possible way to change the size of font for Xcode 4 Project Navigator?

Tinker Tool doesn't help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase the size of the fonts used By XCode 4's GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442400/increase-the-size-of-the-fonts-used-by-xcode-4s-gui)

Comment: I was able to tweak the fonts for most of the Gui using Tinker Tool, but not the Navigator.

Comment: Solutions? The answer to that would be a big NO.