# How to change Xcode 5 GUI font size

Tags: xcode

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442400/increase-the-size-of-the-fonts-used-by-xcode-4s-gui) question pertaining to Xcode 4, I am hoping that apple has provided a solution in Xcode 5 for increasing the size of fonts outside of just in the editor.

Yes, **preferences > fonts & colors** does work for the editor, but that is not my question. Unless my Thunderbolt monitor is directly behind my macbook, the rest of the font on the screen is nearly impossible to read.

Thanks in advance, and if I stumble across the solution, I will be sure to put it up.

Comment: The solution provided seems to be the only option. If anyone has a better answer, I would gladly give credit to where it is deserved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to scale your display (System Preferences) if using the presentation mode in Xcode Preferences Fonts & Colors is not good enough.

[image]

Comment: Dropping resolution, on Apple hardware in order to support Apple software, doesn't seem like much of a solution. I appreciate the insight though.